# Getting Table Value

Tags: javascript, dom, html-table

This should be simple, but I can't seem to get the value for `<td>` `Value3`

How can I traverse this DOM to get the value from `<td>`?

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th col="value2"></th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr id="value1">
       <td>Value3</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody
<table>
```

I am using the below to retrieve other attributes. But can't seem to get the value of `<td>`:

```
        "row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id'),
        "id": this.getAttribute('id'),
        "name": this.getAttribute('row'),
        "project": this.getAttribute('value'),
        "column": oTable.fnGetPosition( this )[2]
```

I have tried the below plus various others with no luck

```
$(table tbody tr td).value
document.getElementsByTagName('tr').getAttribute('value')
```

My table is generated dynamically via JSTL as below.

```
            <c:forEach var="column" items="${row}">
                <td><c:out value="${column}"/></td>
            </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're trying to get the value, but the table's contents are simply HTML. Try this:

```
$('table tbody tr td').html()
```

Comment: That gives me a null value

Answer (score 0):

Value properties in script are for input elements. In this case, Value3 is just text inside the table cell. Try using the text getter:

```
$('td:first').text()
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats works, but only if there is only one value, how how I use this and select only the first value?

Comment: Oops. jsfiddle was showing the table itself, not the jscript output. I've updated it to write the result to a new element in the page, and it now shows the value as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/zWtHj/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `$.each($("table tbody tr td"), function(i,v){alert($(v).text())});`

Comment: Not sure what your trying to do there, looks like that will alert for every value in the entire table.

Comment: you could try this `$($("#value1 td")[0]).text()` and this is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z49Y2/)